# what good is the dimension infomation regarding c# generic types

Tags: c#

So this has been discussed on S.O. before however I don't think I have really ever seen an explanation of why this happens, nor can I seem to glean how this is useful to the average developer trying to use reflection in their code.

So check this bit of code out.

```
var fields = typeof(Person).GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

If I have a `List<int>` in my `Person` object then I will get back a field who's reflection "Name" is set to `` List`1 ``, or if I had a dictionary it would be `` Dictionary`2 ``. On the surface it appears this makes it hard to work with, I can't say the following

```
foreach (var fieldInfo in fields.Where(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(List<int>)))
{
     //Do something.
}
```

The reason this comes up is because I found the following in a project I am currently am working on.

```
    //Initialize collections
    FieldInfo[] properties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (FieldInfo f in properties)
    {
       if (f.FieldType.Name == "IList`1" && f.GetValue(obj) == null)
       {
             object value = Container.Resolve(f.FieldType);
             f.SetValue(obj, value);

       }
   }
```

Then in the configuration for unity I see this happiness

```
<alias alias="IList`1" type="System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

I don't really know that I know this is bad? Is it? It works of course, but even if this is OK (which causes my suspicious-code-dar to go off) my original question remains. What good does the dimension information about the generic do us as programmers?

Comment: When you say "I can't say the following", what do you mean? That loop works as expected, no?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Are you asking why, for example, `Tuple<>`, `Tuple<,>`, `Tuple<,,>` encodes the number of type parameters in there?  (it's because they are distinct types and need to be disambiguated)

Comment: I always thought the compiler-generated name was subject to change, IE, they could in a future release have it generate `IList-LOL\`1` and suddenly your code is all broken.

Comment: @Jasper this name is not compiler-generated.

Comment: No that loop doesn't do anything because there is no type List<int> returned from GetFields(), it will actually be List`1<int> which of course I can't write. Forgive me if I am being confusing but what I mean is I can't write ...fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(List`1<int>))) because that wouldn't compile.

Comment: " there is no type `List<int>` returned from GetFields()" - I just tried a minimal example and it worked as expected. Could you edit your question to include a minimal example that doesn't do what you want?

Comment: +1 @KirkWoll. You can also try writing a `class List<T1, T2> {}` yourself, which would have name List`2. Same class with different arity for their generic parameters need to be disambiguated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with types that are known at compile time, you shouldn't ever need to deal with the `Name` of the `Type`, so names such as `` Thing`n `` shouldn't be an issue.

I'm not sure what's happening in your first example, as when I do this:

```
class Person
{
    private List<int> intList;
}
```

and this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fields = typeof(Person).GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
                                            | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                            | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var fieldInfo in 
            fields.Where(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(List<int>)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

I get what I would expect, namely

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] intList
```

In the code sample you give, again the types are known at compile time; better than what you have shown would be

```
//Initialize collections
FieldInfo[] properties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
                                      | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                      | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (FieldInfo f in properties)
{
   if(typeof(IList<int>).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType)
   && f.GetValue(obj) == null)
   {
         object value = Container.Resolve(f.FieldType);
         f.SetValue(obj, value);
   }
}
```

You *know* what a `IList<int>` is; you can use `IsAssignableFrom` or `==` as appropriate.

<sub>(If you get confused by `IsAssignableFrom`, as I always do, remember this: `if (a is b)` is the same test as `if (typeof(b).IsAssignableFrom(a.getType()))`. The order swaps round.</sub>

Comment: IsAssignableFrom is the key that makes all this useful. I knew you couldn't say: if(theIntList.GetType() is typeof(List<int>)) but I wasn't aware of IsAssignableFrom. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It certainly isn't there to aid a programmer.  It's there because the CLI demands it.  With the further rationale that it ensures generic types with the same identifier name but different number of type arguments have a unique type name. Some verbiage from the ECMA 335 spec:

> CLS Rule 43: The name of a generic type shall encode the number of type parameters declared on the non-nested type, or newly introduced to the type if nested, according to the rules defined above. [Note: CLS (consumer): Need not consume types that violate this rule. CLS (extender): Same as consumers. Extenders choosing to support definition of generic types shall follow this rule for externally visible types. CLS (framework): Shall not expose types that violate this rule. end note]

With some clarification in section II.9:

> A generic type consists of a name followed by a <…>-delimited list of generic parameters, as in `C<T>`. Two or more generic types shall not be defined with the same name, but different numbers of generic parameters, in the same scope. However, to allow such overloading on generic arity at the source language level, CLS Rule 43 is defined to map generic type names to unique CIL names. That Rule states that the CLS-compliant name of a type C having one or more generic parameters, shall have a suffix of the form `` `n ``, where n is a decimal integer constant (without leading zeros) representing the number of generic parameters that C has. For example: the types `C`, `C<T>`, and `C<K,V>` have CLS-compliant names of `C`, C`1<T>, and`C`2<K,V>`, respectively. [Note: The names of all standard library types are CLS-compliant; e.g., System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1. end note]

Sorry, didn't come quite out the correct way, back-quotes are tricky when posting an answer.  Have a look at the ECMA document for accuracy.

Comment: Kirk's comment really causes the light to go on when you give an example using tuples, it isn't as clear when you are testing with a List<> because far as I know you can't have a List<t,t1> or whatever (least I have never seen that). You answer clears it up. What would make my day however is if someone can comment on the wisdom (or lack there of) of doing what they did in this code base, hard coding "IList`1" then creating unity mappings to it - If that is bad decision, what would be the right thing to do there?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of that code, but it smells like some hackorama to get dynamic binding in a heavily statically typed runtime environment.